# Save twitter tweets based on hashtag and/or username

Tags: php, twitter

I was wondering if anybody has made a PHP script that retrieves tweets by hashtag and/or username and then save them into a database? For instance you can imagine this script running once every day collecting all tweets related to some hashtag.